# What's the difference between shuffle phase and combiner phase?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, combiners, partitioner

i'm pretty confused about the MapReduce Framework. I'm getting confused reading from different sources about that. By the way, this is my idea of a MapReduce Job

```
1. Map()-->emit <key,value>  
2. Partitioner (OPTIONAL) --> divide
    intermediate output from mapper and assign them to different
    reducers
3. Shuffle phase used to make: <key,listofvalues>    
4. Combiner,    component used like a minireducer wich perform some
    operations on    datas and then pass those data to the reducer.
    Combiner is on local    not HDFS, saving space and time.    
5. Reducer, get the data from the    combiner, perform further
    operation(probably the same as the    combiner) then release the
    output.     
6.  We will have n outputs parts,    where n is the number
    of reducers
```

It is basically right? I mean, i found some sources stating that combiner is the shuffle phase and it basically groupby each record by key...

Comment: Does the number in your message represent the sequence in which each operation happens ?

Comment: Yes, in my mind yes.

Comment: cool, anyways, I think below answer explains the point.

Comment: Have a look at related SE question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141631/what-is-the-purpose-of-shuffling-and-sorting-phase-in-the-reducer-in-map-reduce/33395854#33395854

Answer (score 5):

Combiner is NOT at all similar to the shuffling phase. What you describe as shuffling is wrong, which is the root of your confusion.

**Shuffling** is just copying keys from map to reduce, it has nothing to do with key generation. It is the first phase of a Reducer, with the other two being sorting and then reducing.

**Combining** is like executing a reducer locally, for the output of each mapper. It basically acts like a reducer (it also extends the Reducer class), which means that, like a reducer, it groups the local values that the mapper has emitted for the same key.

**Partitioning** is, indeed, assigning the map output keys to specific reduce tasks, but it is not optional. Overriding the default HashPartitioner with an implementation of your own is optional.

I tried to keep this answer minimal, but you can find more information on the book Hadoop: The Definitive Guide by Tom White, as Azim suggests, and some related things in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169760/2516301).

Answer (score 3):

Think of combiner as a mini-reducer phase that only works on the output of map task within each node before it emits it to the actual reducer.

Taking the classical WordCount example, map phase output would be (word,1) for each word the map task processes. Lets assume the input to be processed is

> "She lived in a big house with a big garage on the outskirts of a big
>   city in India"

Without a combiner, map phase would emit (big,1) three times and (a,1) three times and (in,1) two times. But when a combiner is used, the map phase would emit (big,3), (a,3) and (in,2). Note that the individual occurrences of each of these words is aggregated locally within the map phase before it emits its output to reduce phase. In use cases where Combiner is used, it would optimise to ensure network traffic from map to reduce is minimised due to local aggregation.

During the shuffle phase, output from various map phases are redirected to the correct reducer phase. This is handled internally by the framework. If a partitioner is used, it would be helpful to shuffle the input to reduce accordingly.

Comment: Try to look at this tutorial :[link]https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#functionality[/link]

But, how can the combiner make the sum if the shuffle phase has not been performed yet? I mean, to sum the values in list of values, you need to stay after the shuffle phase! 
IMHO, combiner can act before the shuffle phase or immediately after, depending on the kind of data he receive as inputs. For example, in wordcount, the combiner will perform the sum of each partition and then, this will go to the real reducer on hdfs.  Understand what i mean? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that combiner is a part of Shuffle and Sort phase.
Combiner, itself is one of the phases(optional) of the job lifecycle.

The pipelining of these phases could be like: 
Map --> Partition --> Combiner(optional) --> Shuffle and Sort --> Reduce

Out of these phases, Map, Partition and Combiner operate on the same node. 
Hadoop dynamically selects nodes to run Reduce Phase depend upon the availability and accessibility of the resources in best possible way.
Shuffle and Sort, an important middle level phase works across the Map and Reduce nodes.

When a client submits a job, Map Phase starts working on input file which is stored across nodes in the form of blocks.
Mappers process each line of the file one by one and put the result generated into some memory buffer of 100MB(local memory to each mapper). When this buffer gets filled till a certain threshold, by default 80%, this buffer is sorted and then stored into the disk(as file). Each Mapper can generate multiple such intermediate sorted splits or files. When Mapper is done with all the lines of the block, all such splits are merged together(to form a single file), sorted(on the basis of key) and then Combiner phase starts working on this single file. Note that, if there is no Paritition phase, only one intermediate file will be produced, but in case of Parititioning multiple files get generated depending upon the developers logic. Below image from **Oreilly Hadoop: The Definitive guide**, may help you in understanding this concept in more details.

[image]

Later, Hadoop copies merged file from each of the Mapper nodes to the Reducer nodes depending upon the key value. That is all the records of the same key will be copied to the same Reducer node.

I think, you may know in depth about SS and Reduce Phase work, so not going into more details for these topics.

Also, for more information, I would suggest you to read Oreilly Hadoop: The Definitive guide. Its awesome book for Hadoop.

Comment: partition is not optional, overriding the default partitioner is optional.