# Number of files in Mapper job without Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I set Reducer to 0, running only Mapper job. Lets say 10 Nodes are executing the Mapper job.
I understand 10 Mappers produces 10 files in HDFS. But, how many number of files would be produced as in final output for the result?

Comment: ... You answered your own question, no?

Comment: No.say if reducers enabled and despite number of reducers executed the aggregation, the result file will be one. So my question is about how many number of files without reducers?

Comment: But reducers aren't enabled... You said you set it to zero. You also said 10 mappers makes 10 files, which is correct, so what is your actual question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A job without reducers is a Map-only job, every mapper will produce an output file.

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621466/will-there-be-shuffle-and-sort-in-map-only-task/42621889#42621889) out: `

> When you have a map-only task, there is not shuffling at all, which
>   means that mappers will write the final output directly to the HDFS.

Comment: So will there be multiple files for the user to check from hdfs?

Comment: @Sathish Yes. Unless you have 1reduce, that way you will have to check only one file. However, that reduce potentially will become a bottleneck.

Comment: Agree. So, if 5 reducers enabled, then the end result file will be one, isn't it?

Comment: If 5 reducers enabled, then you will have 5 files as an output.

Comment: Grand. Thank you !