# Hadoop - can mapper output exceed block size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mapper

We have dfs.blocksize set to 512MB for one of the map reduce jobs which is a map only job. But, some of the mappers are outputting more than 512 MB. ex: 512.9 MB.

I believe, the mapper block size should be restrained by the dfs.blocksize. Appreciate any inputs. Thanks

Comment: File size != block size

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe, the mapper block size should be restrained by the
>   dfs.blocksize.

This is not true. Files can be larger than block size. They'll just span multiple blocks in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Mappers do not save their outputs in HDFS - they use regular file systems for saving results - this is done to not replicate temporary data accross server in HDFS cluster. So, HDFS block size has nothign to do with mappers' output file size.

Comment: Mappers can save to HDFS. Have you not seen a part-m-0000 file?

Comment: @cricket_007 - you can set mapper to save to HDFS or it will be saved there if no reduce jobs are run. However, in most cases it is not. See [here](http://mlwiki.org/index.php/Hadoop_MapReduce) and [here](http://data-flair.training/forums/topic/in-map-reduce-why-map-write-output-to-local-disk-instead-of-hdfs)

Comment: Sure. I'm just clarifying your statement "do not save", when, in fact, they can.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that MapReduce jobs can be Map-only jobs which does not have any shuffle involved. In that case, Mappers will write the final output directly to the HDFS (see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621466/will-there-be-shuffle-and-sort-in-map-only-task/42621889#42621889)