# Is job.setNumReduceTasks(0) equivalent to having a blank reduce function

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

`job.setNumReduceTasks(0)` results in a map only job

does this mean intermediate phase (shuffle and sort) are not performed?

how is it compared to having an empty reduce method (no operations):

```
public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {                             
    \\do nothing            
  }
}
```

Or is it equivalent

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simple,

1. **Map-Only Job**
   In a Map-only job, you do not have shuffle phase, which means no data is sending across the network. The mappers will generate automatically the results. [Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42621466/will-there-be-shuffle-and-sort-in-map-only-task/42621889#42621889)
2. **Map-Reduce Job** Even though your reducers are doing nothing, the data will be sent to the reducers, which means, shuffle phase is happening. Reducers will write the results to disk.