# Which metrics to measure the efficiency of a MapReduce application?

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, metrics

I wrote a MapReduce application which run on 6 nodes of computers.
I am sure that my MapReduce algorithm (run on a cluster of computers) outperforms the sequential algorithm (run on a single computer), but I think this does not mean that my MapReduce algorithm is efficiently enough, right?

I have searched around and found: **speedup, scaleup, and sizeup** metrics. Is it true that we normally consider these metrics when measuring the efficiency of MapReduce application? Is there any metric that we need to consider?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: do you want a tool to measure?

Comment: no, I want to confirm whether those metrics are normally used to measure the efficiency of an application or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before specifically addressing your question, let's revisit the map-reduce model and see what's the real problem, it tries to solve. You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429029/5715934) (by me/ of course you can refer other good answers for the same problem), to get an idea of map-reduce model.

So what it really tries to solve? It deduces a **generic** model that can be applied to solve vast a range of problems that needs to process a massive amount of data (usually in GBs or even Peta Bytes). And the real deal of this model is, it can be **easily parallelized** and can even be **easily distributed** the execution **among number of nodes**. This [article](http://theretardedprogrammer.blogspot.com/2017/09/map-reduce-in-out.html) (by me) has some detailed explanation of whole model.

So let's go to your question, you are asking about measuring the **efficiency of a map reduce program** based on **speed, memory-efficiency and scalability**.

Speaking to the point, the **efficiency of a map-reduce program** always depend on **how far it enjoys the parallelism** given by the **underlying computational** power. This directly indicates that a map-reduce program runs on one cluster may not be the ideal program to run in a different cluster. So we need to have a good idea of our cluster, if we hope to build up our program to a precisely fine-tuned level. But practically its rare some one needs to get it tuned up to that much level.

Let's take your points one by one:

- Speed up:
  It depends on how you split your input to different portions. This directly deduces the amount of parallelism (in human control). So as I mentioned above, the speed-up directly depends on how your split logic going to be able to utilize your cluster.
- Memory efficiency: 
  It mostly depends on how memory efficient your mapper logic and reducer logic are.
- Scalability:
  This is mostly out of concern. You can see that the map-reduce model is already highly scalable to a level that one would rarely think about an extra mile.

So speaking as a whole, **efficiency of a map reduce program** is **rarely a concern** (even speed and memory). Practically speaking the most valuable metric is the quality of its output. i.e. how good your analytic data are. (in place of marketing, research etc.)